# Coldfusion validate list of emails

Tags: validation, email, coldfusion

I am trying to validate a list of emails that have been pulled from the database.

```
<cfquery name="AdminEmail" datasource="#blah#">
Select email from users where role = "admin" 
<cfquery>

<cfset variable.mailto = #adminemail.Email#>
```

The query would return multiple emails which is fine for cfmail, but IsValid only validates a single variable. Any advice. This is needed to get to the security standards asked of me.

Comment: Look at looping over your query results and doing the isValid() method inside the loop. Then handle them however you need from there.

Comment: fyi you do not need the `#` when setting your variable

Comment: Validate them on the way in so you don't have to worry about it on the way out.

Comment: Dan,  they are validated on the way in. I am required to validate on the way in and out. Paranoid much?

Answer (score 4):

Loop through the query of your emails and then add them to a new variable if they're valid.

```
<cfset validEmails = []>
<cfloop query="adminemail">
  <cfif isValid('email', adminemail.email)>
    <cfset arrayAppend(validEmails, adminemail.email)>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfset mailTo = arrayToList(validEmails)>
```

Note: I used an array to store the emails because appending to a list is a more costly process and an array will be slightly faster. Probably nothing you'll notice unless you have hundreds of emails but still a good practice.

Comment: This works great. If you're on cf11/lucee you can also take advantage of arrayFilter: [see trycf.com example](http://trycf.com/editor/gist/304f7db3607a86632852/acf11?theme=solarized_dark)

Comment: Matt - Why are you using a "list" loop, instead of a "query" loop? From the description it sounds like they are using a normalized table structure..